# Token for custom field returns the token but not the Values. How to fix it?

Tags: custom-fields, tokens

when I Insert a token of a custom field to print a pdf letter all built-in token seems working but not the custom ones, no value works, regardless of the number I put in the token. Do you know where the problem is please?
[image]

this is the link where I got "50" from :http://abcd.org/civicm/...update?action=update&reset=1&gid=18&id=50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you are trying to do is to print Gift-Aid custom value in the PDF letter so you need use Token hooks - and assign an new token name for the gift-aid custom values by creating an new extension so the token will be available in the drop down list and you can print the values

do the same for all custom values

Comment: I am printing PDF from  contact_summary screen. And I do not have any PDF extension..

Comment: Which version of Civicrm are you using - I have just created an Example in Demo (http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contact/view?reset=1&cid=202) try this please

Comment: I'm on civicdm 4.6.8

Comment: did you check my example against Demo - that is working fine - so please try to reinstall civicrm again - if possible

Comment: Yes, I have tried on demo site prior to posting and it was working fine. 
My site is a production site, don't I have to do all over again if I reinstall civi?

Comment: best thing is try to disable all the extension - first and try - it might be some extension is causing this issue - please try this and let me know

Comment: ok, doing now..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27424/discussion-between-ramesh-and-tapash).

Comment: what you are trying to do is to print Gift-Aid custom value in the PDF letter
so what you need to do is to use Token hooks - and assign a new token name for the gift-aid custom values
by creating a new extension
so the token will be available in the drop down list and you can print the values

Comment: Example
function civicrm_example_civicrm_tokens( &$tokens ) {
$tokens['contact']['contact.address_block'] = 'Address block';
}

function civicrm_example_civicrm_tokenValues(&$values, $cids, $job = null, $tokens = array(), $context = null){

foreach($cids as $id){
//assign the value here by selecting it from DB
$values[$id]['contact.address_block'] = 'test the process';
}
}

Comment: but why the existing method given by civicrm is not working? is it broken? or a bug?

Comment: Any custom field created for contact can be accessed directly - other than contact (say like gift aid - is created for contact type - individual ) which has to be accessed by above step

Comment: ok, i understand. Many Thanks for your time &  help

Comment: are you free to chat for couple min